# Memory issues for creating predictions using a pytorch model

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, bigdata

I have made a simple neural network in pytorch and already trained it. Now, I want to pass a relatively big data set and save predictions of the model. The dataset is about 40million rows and 5 columns all containing float values. I run this model on an instance with 12 CPUs and 128GB memory available. I use dataloader in pytorch to break the data into different batch sizes and after around 10% of data is passed for predictions, the instance runs out of memory. I used htop command to see how the process goes and all CPUa are almost fully utilized and memory quickly gets used to it's max. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Although limiting memory usage has just been merged to pytorch main branch (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/18626), it is still in unstable phase. It is hard to suggest proper optimizations without the code here.

Comment: I din't post the code because the code is so stereotypical, like I am not doing anything special, I literally load the data in a data loader and call the model for the data in the iterator dataloader. Is this the part that can help if I post? @BijayRegmi